# How to effect multiple web pages using single javascript file execution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dojo

I have two different web pages(**Part of same website**) and a single javascript file .

Suppose user logs into the website and opens both web pages in two different browser windows.
What I want is that, single execution of javascript should make effect on both the web pages . This should happen simultaneously .

Javascript should not be loaded in both browser window and execute as separate instance(Not acceptable). There should be single execution(same instance) , effecting both pages.

All this is required to have variable values, parameters and function calls similar for both pages.

Is this possible at all?

Note: Is it possible if second page comes on clicking the link on first page .

Comment: You could have jquery (or javascript) check if it is supposed to change stuff on the website, but i don't think you could do it with the same javascript code. That would be a big security problem, as a website could change the content on other websites that's open at the same time.

Comment: I am taking about the pages inside same website . There are not different websites.

Comment: as far as javascript is concerned, they are on different websites, as they use different html files

Comment: Question is very unclear, please rephrase.  If you can't post code, it's likely not a good for for stackoverflow. If you have separate windows, you will have to load the same JS twice, second time from cache. If you want your pages to update as other pages change, you need have them communicate with JS or have the all update state in the server and all the pages have to poll or use a web socket to be notified of changes

Answer (score 0):

for browse security reasons this is not possible out of the box. you can look in to using JavaScript an continuity pool the server for changes. (while aswell informing it of its changes)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use websockets to synchronize more then one insances of a site, like when one login the other one will too. You can send in one script the function name and it's paramters to the server via socket, the server will need to send this data to all clients with the same remote adress and while reading data from socket (in client) execute those functions. But you will need to identify the sender script with some ID (it can be timestamp of starting the script) so you don't execute functions twice (and a posible endless repeating of execution).

Answer (score 0):

It is doable.Open page 1 first and then open page 2 as popup.Keep your javascript in page 1.Use javascript window.opener.XX syntax to manipulate elements in page 2.

Comment: He need the solution that will work when the user open two pages in two different tabs, not by a script.